# Can I power and use 1 small voltmeter for 3 12v batteries in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis, series, voltmeter

I asked this question for 4 voltmeters before, and received some great feedback. Unfortunately, it generated too much heat. This is the design I'm thinking of implementing now, but I want to make sure I'm not going to cause a short. Will this work?
[image: CircuitLab Schematic rnxz34tnnbut]

Comment: We can't tell you if it works or not, because you haven't told us anything about the meter, so we don't know how it works.

Comment: Sorry. It is a 3-wire voltmeter able to measure from 0 to 100 volts. It can be powered by 3 to 30 volts.

Comment: We need info about voltmeter?  The 1 or the 4 because any quality voltmeter should not create any heat,

Comment: Actually, I was trying to get the make and model of the meter to get more info about it, like a manual how to connect and use it, instead of a general description about the meter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work. It will drain the battery 3 a bit more than the others.

Comment: thanks. Will that affect recharging and battery health over time?

Comment: The batteries in the electric scooter last about an hour before needing to be recharged.

Comment: It will obviously tend to unbalance the batteries. If they are charged individually it probably won't matter. If they are charged in series and the meter is left on for a long time without driving the motor it will be more significant. I would consider a push-to-read switch.